# Is there a standard host name for the default gateway?

Tags: networking, dns, gateway

I'm configuring a proprietary device to act as a DHCP client. I also must specify in the configuration the IP address or host name of an application server the device needs to connect to. In my case, the application server is always the DHCP server.

As a DHCP client, the device receives a gateway address, which in my case is always the DHCP server's address. But I need to specify the application server in the device's config before the DHCP request is performed.

I can hardcode the DHCP server's address in the config and everything works, but is obviously fragile. If I could just specify "the IP address of the gateway you'll receive from the DHCP server" then I'd have a much more portable setup.

Is there a hostname which means "the gateway you'll receive from the DHCP server"? I tried 0.0.0.0 but that failed. Is there something like `gateway.local` that the device might be able to resolve? If not, the DHCP server is also running dnsmasq, so my fallback might be to add a hostname there, but I'd prefer to use conventions if they exist.

For what it's worth, I don't know what OS the device is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a hostname which means "the gateway you'll receive from the DHCP server"?

No, because there's no way to resolve that to an IP address before DHCP configuration is complete.

Depending on the network configuration, that address may not even exist, or may not be unique.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard domain name which means "default gateway". There is nothing stopping you from creating a DNS entry for your gateway in the DNS for a domain you control, although that only abstracts rather then eliminates the problem.

Comment: On my personal network, my gateway's (router's) intranet-resolvable (but not internet-resolvable) hostname is `gateway.winny`. A more generalized hostname might be `gateway.lan`.

Comment: Thank you. I've opted to add something of my own choosing to the server's `hosts` file, but as you say it's just an abstraction since I still need to specify the IP address! `dnsmasq` very nearly does better with its `domain` option. Unfortunately that strictly specifies a TLD for a collection of hosts, not a FQDN for the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no cross-platform/RFC-standard way, some name-resolution packages on Linux do define a stable hostname for the default gateway:

- [systemd-resolved](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved/) defines `_gateway` ([man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#Synthetic%20Records))
- [libnss-gw-name](http://www.joachim-breitner.de/projects#libnss-gw-name) defines `gateway.localhost`

Unfortunately, both of those may potentially clash with existing usages; systemd may theoretically conflict with a host on the local network, while libnss-gw-name contradicts [RFC 6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761) § 6.3.3 (and [Chromium will refuse to resolve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667118/3840170)). Something under `.arpa` would probably have a smaller chance of conflict.

Comment: These are both promising options, but both appear to only provide services to the local machine. In my case, it is the third party device which needs to resolve the gateway's IP address. So if additional software is required, it needs to be running on the DHCP server machine (which is also the gateway, is running Linux and I have full control over) that allows the client to resolve its IP address. I did discover the third party device is running vsftpd, suggesting it's Linux-like. Alas it still resolves neither of those two addresses.